# Non linear map that accomplishes $f(v+u) = f(v) + f(u)$

Tags: functions

Can someone give an example of a non linear map, $f: V \to V$ that accomplishes $f(v+u) = f(v) + f(u)$ for all $v$, $u$ in $V$, but does not accomplish $k f(v) = f(kv)$ for some $k$ in $K$? ($V$ is a vector space over $K$.)

Answer (score 2):

let $V=\mathbb{C}$, complex filed, and $c=a+ib$ where both $a$ & $b$ are nonzero. define $f(z)=\overline{cz}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $a + b\sqrt{2} \to a - b\sqrt{2}$ for $k = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $V = k$.